# gio operation not supported in a cron task

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-20.04

I have a task (script) that I added via `crontab -e` (Ubuntu 20.04). The task uses gio to copy a file in /tmp (that was created a line before in the script) to Google Drive. Running the gio command in a shell works fine, but it fails in the task. The failure is

```
gio: file:///tmp/wiki.tar.bz2: Operation not supported
```

Why it it working under the shell but not the task? The task runs under my user (as I can see using `whoami` and `id` in the script and also the file that is created is owned by me)

The script is

```
#! /bin/bash

cd ~/
tar jcvf /tmp/wiki.tar.bz2 Wiki
gio copy /tmp/wiki.tar.bz2 google-drive://ittay@company.com/
```

Comment: What does the complete cron task look like?

Comment: I suggest using a shell script for cronjobs so you can add any tests or environment variables.  I do suspect that your issue is that you have selinux and cron jobs running under a different security context.  Someone had a similar issue here:   Seehttps://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671170/permission-denied-inside-a-cron-script

Comment: @larsks, added the entire job. Not sure if it adds much information. As mentioned, the last line works if pasted in a shell

Comment: @toppk, it is indeed a shell script that I run.

Comment: @toppk, when I run `id -Z` I get `id: --context (-Z) works only on an SELinux-enabled kernel`. So I assume selinux is not involved here.

Comment: cron runs under a very limited environment set.    you can simulate this by running "env - /path/to/scrip".  See if it works under that circumstance.  I suspect that since it is gnome software it is missing some of the XDG_* variables.

Comment: @toppk, that is it. you can write as an answer.